# How can I add headers to ckfinder for image upload

Tags: vue.js, jwt, richtext

I use Vue, CKEditor and a JWT Auth Api with Laravel. I like to upload images from the CKEditor with CKFinder. I like to add the headers, but it's not working. The `Authorization` Header is missing in the request.

```
            editor: ClassicEditor,

            editorConfig: {
                // toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote','insertTable','|', 'undo', 'redo', 'image'],

                fillEmptyBlocks: false,
                basicEntities: false,
                entities: false,
                entities_greek: false,
                entities_latin: false,
                entities_additional: "",
                language: "de",
                wordCount: {
                    container: document.getElementById("wordcount")
                },
                ckfinder: {

                    uploadUrl: '/api/media/temporaryUpload',

                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer <JSON Web Token>'
                    }
                },

                mediaEmbed: {
                    previewsInData: true
                }
            }
        }),
```

I'm not sure if headers are working with ckfinder. Has someone an answer on it?